# What causes the error "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated?"

Tags: debugging

My understanding is that objects in PHP 5.3 are all passed by reference so using the &$ notation is not necessary. My problem is using date_views module where I'm getting this error.

```
Deprecated function: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in
 _registry_check_code() (line 2701 of C:\wamp\www\cruzr\includes\bootstrap.inc).
```

The affected lines of the code are:

```
  // $type is either 'interface' or 'class', so we only need the first letter to
  // keep the cache key unique.
  $cache_key = $type[0] . $name;
  if (isset($lookup_cache[$cache_key])) {
    exit;
    if ($lookup_cache[$cache_key]) {
      require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $lookup_cache[$cache_key];
    }
    return (bool) $lookup_cache[$cache_key];
  }
```

How do I test if a variable is passed by reference? With several classes being loaded how do I approach debugging this problem?

Comment: What contains line 2701 exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in
 _registry_check_code()" is a file that holds a class being loaded that contains a variable that is passed by reference that is not in a function definition.

Drupal 7 requires PHP 5.2 or higher and [PHP 5 always passes objects into functions by reference](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#php_version)

This was a difficult bug to find because enabling a feature of the Date Views module is what triggered it. However, the problem was in the Workbench Moderation module. What I did was set the breakpoint in the debugger on function drupal_set_message() then worked back through the call stack till I found the offending variable.

Problem was not exactly in the Date module but was nonetheless triggered by the Date module in line 53 of date_views_fields.inc.

```
// If we don't have a filter handler, we don't need to do anything more.
if (!$handler = views_get_handler($table_name, $field_name, 'filter')) {
  continue; 
}
```

This would iterate through all the view's handlers including workbench_moderatioin_handler_filter_user_can_moderate which passed a variable by reference not in a function definition,     parent::options_form(&$form, &$form_state);. Simply the Workbench moderation module needs to be patched to reflect changes in code in PHP 5.3